# How to change complete layout on mobile device in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

i m building an online store i want to change complete layout on mobile device like e-bay or amazon looking like mobile application in reactjs.Is there is anyway to change complete layout?

Answer (score 1):

You could use media queries in your css which would allow certain css to be applied only to mobile devices or devices of a certain width. For example, this would make the background blue for any device that isn't > 600px wide

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```